# Add column to dataframe based on date range

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I want to add a column to my data frame `prod_data` based on a range of dates. This is an example of the data in the column `['Mount Time']` I want to modify the new column from:

```
0     2022-08-17 06:07:00
1     2022-08-17 06:12:00
2     2022-08-17 06:40:00
3     2022-08-17 06:45:00
4     2022-08-17 06:47:00
```

The new column is named `['Week']` and I want it to run from M-S, with week 1 starting on 9/5/22, running through 9/11/22 and then week 2 the next M-S, and so on until the last week which would be 53. I would also like weeks previous to 9/5 to have negative week numbers, so 8/29/22 would be the start of week -1 and so on.

The only thing I could think of was to create 2 massive lists and use `np.select` to define the parameters of the column, but there has to be a cleaner way of doing this, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pandas [datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) objects to figure out how many days away a date is from your start date, 9/5/2022, and then use floor division to convert that to week numbers. I made the "mount_time" column just to emphasize that the original column should be a datetime object.

```
prod_data["mount_time"] = pd.to_datetime( prod_data[ "Mount Time" ] )
start_date = pd.to_datetime( "9/5/2022" )
days_away = prod_data.mount_time - start_date
prod_data["Week"] = ( days_away.dt.days // 7 ) + 1
```

As intended, 9/5/2022 through 9/11/2022 will have a value of 1. 8/29/2022 would start week 0 (not -1 as you wrote) unless you want 9/5/2022 to start as week 0 (in which case just delete the + 1 from the code). Some more examples:

```
>>> test[ ["date", "Week" ] ]
        date  Week
0 2022-08-05    -4
1 2022-08-14    -3
2 2022-08-28    -1
3 2022-08-29     0
4 2022-08-30     0
5 2022-09-05     1
6 2022-09-11     1
7 2022-09-12     2
```